# Como sumar todos mis select de mi form y que aparezcan en el total

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero sumar los valores seleccionados de mis `select`, pero me los muestra por separado y al momento de agregarle el `parseint` no me lo muestra, y si me podrían ayudar en saber como hacer para que al momento de seleccionar una opción de mi select este aparezca en el total y no hasta que seleccione todos mis select, me ayudarían mucho gracias.

Aquí le dejo el código de lo que intenté hasta el momento.

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
            <form name="sumar">
    
                <p type="text-align" name="etiqueta1" class="etiqueta1"> Opciónes de impresión </p>
    
                <label>Tipo</label> <br>
                <select name="list1" class="list1">
                    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
                    <option value="100">SIN suaje/pestaña (22.5 x 29.2 cm)</option>
                </select>
                <br>
    
                <label>Cantidad</label> <br>
                <select name="list2" class="list2">
                    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
                    <option value="20">25</option>
                    <option value="40">50</option>
                    <option value="80">100</option>
                    <option value="120">200</option>
                    <option value="160">300</option>
                    <option value="300">500</option>
                </select>
                <br>
    
                <label>Impresión</label> <br>
                <select name="list3" class="list3">
                    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
                    <option value="50">4/0 (Color solo frente)</option>
                    <option value="100">4/4 (Color frente y vuelta)</option>
                </select>
                <br>
    
                <label>Tipo de papel</label> <br>
                <select name="list4" class="list4">
                    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
                    <option value="200">Coché 300 g</option>
                    <option value="300">Cartulina sulfatada 12 pts 1 cara</option>
                </select>
                <br>
    
                <p type="text-align" name="etiqueta1" class="etiqueta1">  Terminados </p>
    
                <label>Plastificado frente y vuelta</label> <br>
                <select name="list5" class="list5">
                    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
                    <option value="150">Delgado brillante (BOPP)</option>
                    <option value="300">Delgado mate (BOPP)</option>
                </select>
                <br>
    
                <label>Esquinas redondeadas (con datos de contacto hacia arriba)</label> <br>
                <select name="list6" class="list6">
                    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
                    <option value="0">Ninguna</option>
                    <option value="80">4</option>
                </select>
                <br> <br>
                
                <label>Total</label>
                <input type="text" name="total">
    
            </form>
    
   
            <script>
                var numero3, numero1, numero2, numero4, numero5, numero6;
            caja = document.forms["sumar"].elements;
    
            $(".list1").change(function() {
              numero1 = caja["list1"].value;
              mostrar();
            });
            
            $(".list2").change(function() {
              numero2 = caja["list2"].value;
              mostrar();
            });
    
            $(".list3").change(function() {
              numero3 = caja["list3"].value;
              mostrar();
            });
    
            $(".list4").change(function() {
              numero4 = caja["list4"].value;
              mostrar();
            });
    
            $(".list5").change(function() {
              numero5 = caja["list5"].value;
              mostrar();
            });
    
            $(".list6").change(function() {
              numero6 = caja["list6"].value;
              mostrar();
            });
    
    
            function mostrar() {
                if (numero1 >= 0 && numero2 >= 0 && numero3 >= 0 && numero4 >= 0 && numero5 >= 0 && numero6 >= 0) {
                    var resultado = 0;
                    resultado = (numero1 + numero2 + numero3 + numero4 + numero5 + numero6);
                    caja["total"].value = (resultado);  
                }
            }
    
            </script>
    
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener todos los `select` de una vez con un selector, luego sumas los valores con `.reduce`. Para que se actualice el valor se puede usar el evento "change" de los selects. Para simplificar el código, se le puede otorgar un valor de 0 a los que aún no seleccionó.

```js
const selects = [...document.getElementsByTagName("select")];

const total = document.getElementById("total")

selects.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("change", () => 

    total.value = selects.reduce((p, c) =>+c.value+p,0)  

));
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
            <form name="sumar">
    
                <p type="text-align" name="etiqueta1" class="etiqueta1"> Opciónes de impresión </p>
    
                <label>Tipo</label> <br>
                <select name="list1" class="list1">
                    <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
                    <option value="100">SIN suaje/pestaña (22.5 x 29.2 cm)</option>
                </select>
                <br>
    
                <label>Cantidad</label> <br>
                <select name="list2" class="list2">
                    <option  value="0" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
                    <option value="20">25</option>
                    <option value="40">50</option>
                    <option value="80">100</option>
                    <option value="120">200</option>
                    <option value="160">300</option>
                    <option value="300">500</option>
                </select>
                <br>
    
                <label>Impresión</label> <br>
                <select name="list3" class="list3">
                    <option  value="0" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
                    <option value="50">4/0 (Color solo frente)</option>
                    <option value="100">4/4 (Color frente y vuelta)</option>
                </select>
                <br>
    
                <label>Tipo de papel</label> <br>
                <select name="list4" class="list4">
                    <option  value="0" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
                    <option value="200">Coché 300 g</option>
                    <option value="300">Cartulina sulfatada 12 pts 1 cara</option>
                </select>
                <br>
    
                <p type="text-align" name="etiqueta1" class="etiqueta1">  Terminados </p>
    
                <label>Plastificado frente y vuelta</label> <br>
                <select name="list5" class="list5">
                    <option  value="0" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
                    <option value="150">Delgado brillante (BOPP)</option>
                    <option value="300">Delgado mate (BOPP)</option>
                </select>
                <br>
    
                <label>Esquinas redondeadas (con datos de contacto hacia arriba)</label> <br>
                <select name="list6" class="list6">
                    <option  value="0" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
                    <option value="0">Ninguna</option>
                    <option value="80">4</option>
                </select>
                <br> <br>
                                
                <label>Total</label>
                <input id="total" type="text" name="total">
    
            </form>
    
        </body>
        </html>
```

idealmente sería mejor indicar con un mismo nombre de clase a todos los `selects` que quieres sumar.